# How to download a tag information from an OSM large dataset

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I need to download the building center coordinates and number of floors of all US buildings for which the tag "building:levels" is available.

I've been trying for the last 3 hours to do this.

1. Using Overpass Turbo
   So far, I have come up with that query:

```
[out:json];
area["is_in:country_code"="US"]->.boundaryarea;
way["building:levels"]({{bbox}})->.buildings;

.buildings out noids tags center;
```

but it is too big and the query times out.
Also the json returns a list of tags for each building but I don't need all tags, I just need "building:levels" so that's a waste of resources.

2. Downloading planet.osm
   Out of desperation, I'm currently downloading Planet.osm even if I still have no idea what I am going to do with it. I feel that this is not the right way as the dataset I need is probably not that big.
   I mean it is just at maximum the number of buildings in the US (200 millions) times a building level and a coordinate (one integer, two floats).

Could someone point me with some easy way to perform this ?

PS: I have read https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data but it goes into so many direction and I feel totally lost...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you define ".boundaryarea" when you're using a bounding box {{bbox}} in the end?

Answer (score 1):

If you need just the US and not the whole planet then check the [OSM country and area extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). Afterwards you can extract your desired data via [osmium-tool](https://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/).

Comment: This makes more sense in this case. By the way, you would have to download about 1.2 million ways with a building:level tag in the US.